# Adding price based on ChoiceBox selection

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I am making Car Care Center GUI using javaFX and Scenebuilder and I was doing good until I faced one problem.

Problem is really simple though. Basically, I made this one choice box which user can choose to replace Regular tire($225) or Sports tire($310).
And I have to add the cost to the sum (variable name = `costSum`). 
 If user selects Regular tire in choicebox first, `costSum` adds only $225.

Then if user selects sports tire, it is supposed to add only $310 (not $225 for regular tire) but `costSum` adds both 225 and 310 because $225 was added to `costSum` before selecting Sports tire.

I know why this is happening but I just cannot find way to solve this even thought it looks simple.

Is there a way to reset value of `costSum` to original value before user select choice from choicbox?

To simplifiy my question, How can I add only one value of cost to the `costSum` when user selects each different option (Regular tire, Sports tire)?

Below is code for that choice box:

```
@FXML
void onSelectTireReplacementChoice(ActionEvent event) {

    if(tireReplacementChkBox.isSelected()){
        tireReplacementChoiceBox.setDisable(false);     
        tireReplacementChoiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

            public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Number value, Number selection) {

                if(selection.intValue() == 0){
                    costSum += REGULAR_TIRE;                 
                }

                if(selection.intValue() == 1){
                    costSum += SPORTS_TIRE;                    
                 }
         ;
                String cost = "Service Cost: " + "$" + df.format(costSum);
                serviceCostLabel.setText(cost);   
            }
        });
    } else{
      //  costSum += initialCost;
        String cost = "Service Cost: " + "$" + df.format(costSum);
        serviceCostLabel.setText(cost);
        tireReplacementChoiceBox.setDisable(true);     
    }       

}
```

And this is whole code (I did not finish yet though):

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    public double costSum = 0;
    public double costOnCustomerType;
    public boolean update;
    public int choice;
    public double sum = 0;

    String cost = "Service Cost: " + "$";

    final double BRAKES = 27.27;
    final double FLUID_CHK = 9.09;
    final double CAR_WASH = 4.54;
    final double EMMISION_INSPECTION = 36.37;
    final double TIRE_ROTATION = 18.18;
    final double REGULAR_TIRE = 225.22;
    final double SPORTS_TIRE = 315.32;
    final double REGULAR_OIL = 13.64;
    final double SYNTHETIC_OIL = 24.54;

    public double initialCost ;

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton newCustomerRadioButton;

    @FXML
    private ToggleGroup customerType;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton regularCustomerRadioButton;

    @FXML
    private TextField nameTextField;

    @FXML
    private TextField phoneTextField;

    @FXML
    private TextField addressTextField;

    @FXML
    private TextField emailTextField;

    @FXML
    private Button printInvoiceButtion;

    @FXML
    private Label serviceCostLabel;

    @FXML
    private Button resetButton;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox brakesChkBox;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox tireRotationChkBox;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox fluidChkBox;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox carWashChkBox;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox inspectionChkBox;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox tireReplacementChkBox;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox oilChangeChkBox;

    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox tireReplacementChoiceBox;

     @FXML
    void updateBrakes(ActionEvent event) {

        if(brakesChkBox.isSelected()){
            costSum += BRAKES;
        }else{
            costSum -= BRAKES;
        }

        String cost = "Service Cost: " + "$" + df.format(costSum);
        serviceCostLabel.setText(cost);
    }

     @FXML
    void updateCarWash(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void updateEmmissonInspec(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void updateFluidCheck(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void updateTireRotation(ActionEvent event) {
        if(tireRotationChkBox.isSelected()){  
            costSum += TIRE_ROTATION; 
        } else{
            costSum -= TIRE_ROTATION;    
        }

        serviceCostLabel.setText(cost + df.format(costSum));


    }


    @FXML
    void onChangeServiceCostRequest(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void onSelectOilChange(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void onSelectTireReplacementChoice(ActionEvent event) {

        if(tireReplacementChkBox.isSelected()){
         tireReplacementChoiceBox.setDisable(false);     
         tireReplacementChoiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

                public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Number value, Number selection) {

                    if(selection.intValue() == 0){
                        costSum += REGULAR_TIRE;                 
                    }

                    if(selection.intValue() == 1){
                        costSum += SPORTS_TIRE;                    
                     }
             ;
                    String cost = "Service Cost: " + "$" + df.format(costSum);
                    serviceCostLabel.setText(cost);   
                }
            });
        } else{
          //  costSum += initialCost;
               String cost = "Service Cost: " + "$" + df.format(costSum);
               serviceCostLabel.setText(cost);
         tireReplacementChoiceBox.setDisable(true);     
        }       

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
       tireReplacementChoiceBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("Regular Tire", "Sports TIre"));
       tireReplacementChoiceBox.setDisable(true);


        String cost = "Service Cost: " + "$" + df.format(costSum);
        serviceCostLabel.setText(cost);// TODO

    }    

}
```

Comment: Do not update the value the way you are doing it. You are updating on change. You should update the value on a different action. Like when a button is pressed. You can use the onchange to set a variable, so that when a button is pressed then the right calculation is done. I personally would not use the onchange method at all in this situation. I would get the value using comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() after a button submission. If there is a label on your gui that you want to update on change, in that situation I would use on change.

Comment: Thank you for help! There is no button to press to make change the value My teacher showed us example and there is label that shows total cost and it changes everytime user check Checkbox or ChoiceBox! Then I will just look for using onchange method!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@FXML
void onSelectTireReplacementChoice(ActionEvent event) {
    double newValue = 0;

    if(tireReplacementChkBox.isSelected()){
        tireReplacementChoiceBox.setDisable(false);              

        tireReplacementChoiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

            public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Number value, Number selection) {

                if(selection.intValue() == 0){
                    newValue = REGULAR_TIRE;                 
                }

                if(selection.intValue() == 1){
                    newValue = SPORTS_TIRE;                    
                 }
         ;
                String cost = "Service Cost: " + "$" + df.format(newValue);
                serviceCostLabel.setText(cost);   
            }
        });
    } else{
        costSum = initialCost + newValue;
        String cost = "Service Cost: " + "$" + df.format(costSum);
        serviceCostLabel.setText(cost);
        tireReplacementChoiceBox.setDisable(true);     
    }       

}
```